# Что принято (считается хорошим тоном) передавать как аргумент ф-ции - указатель или массив?

Tags: c++, code-style

```
void foo(int mass[]);
void foo(int *pMass);
```

Как принято делать?

Comment: В С++ хороший тон это `std::vector`

Comment: но если не хочется вектор, то можно и std::array

Comment: Если по делу, то сточки зрения языка разницы нет. Некоторые предпочитают скобки, чтобы явно показать что ожидают массив. Не скажу что я видел много стандартов оформления кода, но те, которые видел, об этом не упоминают. ИМХО, разницы никакой

Comment: У нас в универе учили, что передавать указатель лучше. Насчёт лучше не уверен, но это в некотором смысле стандарт.

Comment: Вообще-то ни то, ни другое в С++ использовать не принято. Второй вариант может использоваться в С.

Comment: Если по смыслу задачи функция работает с массивом, то пишите `foo (int mass[]) { ...}` / Остальным читателям сразу будет более понятно о чем идет речь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запись

```
void foo(int mass[/*сколько-то*/]);//параметр имеет тип int*, а не int[/*сколько-то*/]
```

полностью аналогична записи

```
void foo(int *pMass);
```

по своему функционалу.
Никакой передачи массива в данном случае нет. В обоих случаях передается указатель. Это просто еще одна форма записи одного и того же.

Лично мне более привычен второй вариант, как минимум потому что он более очевидный.

Answer (score 3):

В языке С синтаксис массива отличается от синтаксиса указателя в том, что язык требует, чтобы типа элемента массива был *полным* (*complete*). Также, если в `[]` указан размер массива, то язык требует положительности этого размера. На указательный синтаксис такие ограничения не накладываются. (В языке С++ существует только второе требование).

Также в языке С, пользуясь синтаксисом массива, у вас есть возможность делать объявления вида

```
void foo(int array[static 10])
```

Синтаксис указателя аналогичной возможности не предоставляет. (К С++ не относится)

Эти факторы могут служить *объективными* предпосылками для выбора того или иного синтаксиса.

В остальном оба варианта синтаксиса эквивалентны и вопрос выбора является вопросом персональных предпочтений. При работе с массивами, я лично использую указательный синтаксис тогда, когда передаваемый указатель имеет семантику "итератора", и массивный синтаксис, когда речь идет о передаче ("по указателю") собственно всего массива. Хотя и тут границы размыты.

Answer (score 0):

В стандарте вообще есть указатель на массив неопределённого размера. Можно указывать переменную этого типа. Возвращать указатель на массив. Но почему-то запрещается передавать указатель на безразмерный массив как аргумент функции.

```
typedef int ( & vararray ) [ ] ;  

vararray f ( void  ) {
  int array5  [ 5 ] ;
  int array10 [ 10  ] ;
  int ( * pointer_to_array  ) [ ] = (int(*)[])& array5  ;
  pointer_to_array  = (int(*)[])& array10 ;
  pointer_to_array  = (int(*)[])new int [ 20  ] ;
  ( * pointer_to_array  ) [ 10 ] = 777 ;
  return *pointer_to_array ; }
```

Есть вариант упаковать этот указатель в структуру или класс. Тогда можно передавать указатель как аргумент.

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -Wall pointertoarray2.cpp
# include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template  < class T >
class arrlnk {
public  :
  arrlnk ( void  ) : a { nullptr } { }
  arrlnk ( T * const x ) : a { (T (&)[])*x } { }
  T & operator [] (size_t i) { return  a[i] ; }
private :
  T ( & a ) [ ] ;
} ;

void g(arrlnk<int> a) {
  cout<<"a[10]="<<a[10]<<endl;  }

typedef int ( & vararray ) [ ] ;  

vararray f ( void  ) {
  int array5  [ 5 ] ;
  int array10 [ 10  ] ;
  int ( * pointer_to_array  ) [ ] = (int(*)[])& array5  ;
  pointer_to_array  = (int(*)[])& array10 ;
  pointer_to_array  = (int(*)[])new int [ 20  ] ;
  ( * pointer_to_array  ) [ 10 ] = 777 ;
  return *pointer_to_array ; }

int main() {
  arrlnk<int> array_link = f ( ) ;
  cout <<"array_link [ 10 ]="<<  array_link  [ 10 ]<<endl;
  delete[](&array_link[0]);
  int arr[30];
  arr[10]=888;
  g(arr); }
```

Можно передавать массив как все с помощью указателя на первый элемент, но если нужно чётко определить что аргумент должен быть именно массив, а не указатель на что-то одно, то пользуйтесь таким классом.

Answer (score 0):

Передавать два итератора - на начало и на конец обрабатываемого диапазона. 
Это позволяет отвязать логику обработки данных от логики хранения, как сделано в STL